# Flags, reviews and hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Somehow I saw a sudden burst of flags in the 10k tools for answers that are links to Launchpad flagged as NAA (I presume they are looking for "me too"s). Lets set things straight:

1. If there's an answer to a valid bug report (ie, the bug isn't expired, or invalid) you should evaluate if the bug report is relevant to the question,
2. **Flag the question as bug if the report is related to the question**, and
3. post a comment with the bug report (or the master in case is a duplicated bug) so reviewers doesn't have to hunt down answers.

Secondly, please remember that the hats will end by January 6 of the **next year**. You shouldn't burn through the review queue to get fast. I believe that if everybody gets the same behaviour as when there isn't this kind of events (ie, without rush, overall without rush) you all get the hats.